# Close previous page after clicking Flyout in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, menu, flyout

do you know how to set automatically close the previous page after clicking on Flyout Menu?
I don't want to keep this page in memory of my device, because it lags him.

Any ideas?

I try to create the method "button clicked" with this:

`await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();`

It didn't work.

Comment: Please provide a **minimal reproducible example** showing what you've attempted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example You should include all the relevant parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are trying removes the top Page from the navigation stack, in other words it only pops up one page at a time. You can use the [INavigation.PushAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.inavigation.popasync?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Xamarin.Forms.INavigation.PopAsync)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=xamarin-forms) method to add a page to the stack, which opens a new page on the screen, like this:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new TestPage();
```

Usually you don't need to do anything to clear the previous page. The garbage collector will do this automatically for you (not immediately, but after some time depending on some circumstances).